# jQuery Show Loading Image on Button Click and display the button once job finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cgi

I'm using a button to submit two forms(which will run few scripts at the backend and displays the output on the frontend)".

HTML -

```
 <form id="form2" class="form-wrapper"  name="myForm"  action="http://10.1.6.65/cgi-bin/testresult2.py"  method="get" >
     <div class="container">
     <label><b> Client Name</b></label>
     <input id="clientName_details" placeholder="Enter client name" type="text" name="De_Client_name" required >
     <label><b> Version</b></label>
     <input id="Version_details" placeholder="Enter version" type="text" name="De_version" >
     <label><b> DB Name</b></label>
     <input id="dbName_details" placeholder="Enter DB name" type="text" name="De_dbname"  >
     <label><b> HOST Name</b></label>
     <input id="hostName_details" placeholder="Enter HOST name" type="text" name="De_Host">
     <label><b> Email</b></label>
     <input type="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" value="" required/>
     </div>
     </form>
     <dev class=bottom>
   <form id>
        <dev class=tag><b>Do you want to proceed with Upgrade : </b> </dev>
   <input type="button" id="subbut" value="YES">
   <div id="divMsg"  style="display:none;">
    <img src="http://www.javascriptsource.com/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Please wait.." />
</div>
   <div id="msg"></div>
   </form>
```

JS -

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#subbut").click(function() {
          $(this).parent().append('<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />');
            $.post($("#form1").attr("action"), $("#form1").serialize(),
              function(data) {
                $("#msg").append(data);
                $.post($("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").serialize(),
                  function(data) {
                    $("#msg").append(data);
                      $(this).hide();
                  });
              });
          });
      });
```

But only the problem is the loading is for infinite time.But how can we restrict so that as soon as the code behind Execution completes the loading image should be vanished.

Comment: your are hiding this $(this).hide(); hide the image $(this).parent().find("img").hide();

Comment: Thanks for your response. tried $(this).parent().find("img").hide(); but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simple show/Hide divMsg

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subbut").click(function() {
        $("#divMsg").show();
        $.post($("#form1").attr("action"), $("#form1").serialize(),
          function(data) {
            $("#msg").append(data);
            $.post($("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").serialize(),
              function(data) {
                $("#msg").append(data);
                  $("#divMsg").hide();
              });
          });
      });
  });
```